# Empty array of entries in nuxt / content module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      v-model="searchQuery"
      type="search"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="Search Articles"
    />
    <ul v-if="articles.length">
      <li
        v-for="article in articles"
        :key="article.slug"
      >
        <NuxtLink v-if="$i18n.locale === 'ru'" :to="{ name: 'articles-slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
          {{ article.title }}
        </NuxtLink>
        <NuxtLink
          v-else
          :to="$route.fullPath.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/, `articles/${article.slug}`)"
        >
            {{ article.title }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchInput',
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: '',
      articles: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    async searchQuery({ app, searchQuery }) {
      if (!searchQuery) {
        this.articles = []
        return
      }
      this.articles = await this.$content(`/articles/${ app.i18n.locale }`)
        .limit(6)
        .search(searchQuery)
        .fetch()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have a content module for nuxt, also i18n localization, using the example of the article search component also out of the nuxt / content box, logically it should go to the articles folder and generate links to nested translations, now the problem is that the array is empty tobish it is not included in these nested directories, although I test directly articles / array.md, if not nesting in en and ru and passing a line such as:

```
  watch: {
    async searchQuery(searchQuery) {
      if (!searchQuery) {
        this.articles = []
        return
      }
       this.articles = await this.$content('articles')
        .limit(6)
        .search(searchQuery)
        .fetch()
    }
  }
```

everything is fine, I see the article array.md but if I add a parameter to searchQuery such as app and add en and ru paths in backticks so that it repeats from url, an empty array and there is no error, what could be the problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/otCsA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option worked for me

```
async searchQuery(searchQuery) {
  console.log(this.articles)
  if (!searchQuery) {
    this.articles = []
    return
  }
  this.articles = await this.$content(`/articles/${ this.$root.$i18n.locale }`)
    .limit(6)
    .search(searchQuery)
    .fetch()
}
```